# Rails: searchlogic search with or conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, searchlogic

I'm using the 'binarylogic-searchlogic' gem in version 2.3.5 along with Rails 2.3.4.

What I want to do is performing a search on a model for a specified value over multiple attributes. I achieve this through chaining everything together like

```
User.first_name_or_last_name_or_email_like(value)
```

But with more and more attributes in this search this tends to be ugly. Instead I'd like to use the search mechanism of searchlogic like this:

```
search = User.search
search.first_name_like = value
search.last_name_like  = value
..
@users = search.all
```

So this is the way to search via AND - but what I want is OR. I've found two ways to achieve this, but both don't work.

1st one: prepend an or_ to the condition

```
search = User.search
search.first_name_like = value
search.or_last_name_like  = value
@users = search.all
```

This gives me `The or_last_name_like is not a valid condition. You may only use conditions that map to a named scope`

2nd one: use `search.any`

```
search = User.search
search.first_name_like = value
search.last_name_like  = value
@users = search.any
```

gives me `undefined method`any' for #`.

Any idea's on that? Am I mising the right point of the readme?

Thanks for your very welcome help!

**edit:** time for some ugly workaround:

```
search = User.search
search.first_name_like = value
search.last_name_like  = value
User.find(:all, :conditions => search.scope(:find).gsub('AND','OR'))
```

Works but is surely not the way to go, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's another way of doing it. By default it will join the arguments with AND.

The *OR* code, only seems to work with chaining.

Comment: +1 After a quick look, I agree with this answer. For confirmation, you can ask the Searchlogic mailing list.